# Combining mysql statements from different table depending on the column value

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures, case

I need help on how best to handle this situation.

I have 3 tables, say A, B, C.

Table A has a column `categoryID` with either G (Good) or B (Bad).

- If `categoryID` in A is G, the information about that row is in table B.
- If `categoryID` is B, the information about that row is in C.

For example if i have 2 records in table A.

For the first record, `categoryID` is G. I need to get the data from table B for the first record.

For the second record, `categoryID` is B, I need to get the data from table C for the second record.

I'm using MySQL procedure. I've tried to use case, but doesn't seem to work.

I want to achieve this in a single procedure. Tables B and C have foreign key referenced column from table A.

Comment: Post the procedure you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is two `left join`s.  Your question is a bit vague on what the column names really are, but the approach is something like this:

```
select a.*, coalesce(b.col1, c.col1) as col1, coalesce(b.col2, c.col2) as col2
from a left join
     b
     on a.categoryId = 'G' and a.bid = b.bid left join
     c
     on a.categoryid = 'B' and a.cid = c.cid;
```